# What is a "Push-Constant" in vulkan?

Tags: vulkan

I've looked through a bunch of tutorials that talk about push constants, allude to possible benefits, but never have I actually seen, even in Vulkan docs, what the heck a "push constant" actually is... I don't understand what they are supposed to be, and what the purpose of push constants are.  The closest thing I can find is this [post](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/5536/6530) which unfortunately doesn't ask for what they are, but what are the differences between them and another concept and didn't help me much.

What is a push constant, why does it exist and what is it used for? where did its name come from?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Push constants is a way to quickly provide a small amount of uniform data to shaders. It should be much quicker than UBOs but a huge limitation is the size of data - spec requires 128 bytes to be available for a push constant range. Hardware vendors may support more, but compared to other means it is still very little (for example 256 bytes).

Because push constants are much quicker than other descriptors (resources through which we provide data to shaders), they are convenient to use for data that changes between draw calls, like for example transformation matrices.

From the shader perspective, they are declared through `layout( push_constant )` qualifier and a block of uniform data. For example:

```
layout( push_constant ) uniform ColorBlock {
  vec4 Color;
} PushConstant;
```

From the application perspective, if shaders want to use push constants, they must be specified during pipeline layout creation. Then the `vkCmdPushConstants()` command must be recorded into a command buffer. This function takes, among others, a pointer to a memory from which data to a push constant range should be copied.

Different shader stages of a given pipeline can use the same push constant block (similarly to UBOs) or smaller parts of the whole range. But, what is important, each shader stage can use only one push constant block. It can contain multiple members, though. Another important thing is that the total data size (across all shader stages which use push constants) must fit into the size constraint. So the constraint is not per stage but per whole range.

There is an example in the Vulkan Cookbook's [repository](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook) showing a simple push constant usage scenario. Sascha Willems's [Vulkan examples](https://github.com/SaschaWillems/Vulkan) also contain a sample showing how to use push constants.

Comment: why are they called "push constants" though if they aren't constant?

Comment: In shaders You can only read values stored in a push constant block. So they are constant from the shader perspective (similarly to data in uniform buffers). Why there are called push? Due to way they are managed by the hardware - as far as I know, values of are stored in a command buffer memory. So they are pushed to hardware along other command buffer data.

Comment: So would it be accurate to call them "Pushed Shader constants"? Also I can't find the push constant example in the first link, and the second link I'm not sure how the push constants are getting updated, I see time is used, but it only appears inside the command buffer initialization, so you have to re-create a command buffer if you want to use push constants?

Comment: @snb Push constant sample from the Vulkan Cookbook is available here: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Vulkan-Cookbook/blob/master/Samples/Source%20Files/Other/07-Using_Push_Constants/main.cpp (it is called "07 - Using push constants"). Push constants are updated (populated with data) with the `vkCmdPushConstant()` function for which You provide a pointer to a memory with the data that should be provided to shaders (I've updated my answer). As for recreating command buffers - You don't have to recreate them, re-recording is enough (unless You are asking about something else).

Comment: Where is the Push Constant placed in GPU memory? In global memory, then automatically cached into L2 cache?